# How to archive and create .ipa in one step using command line?

Tags: xcode, bash, cordova

Sorry for the poorly written question. I am using the xCode command line tools to archive and create a .ipa. My only issue is that the archive created is given a timestamped name, which makes it impossible for me to link to it when trying to create a .ipa. I would like to rename the file and then start the export. Is there any way to do this?

```
cd /Users/username/Desktop/MyiOSApp/

xcodebuild -scheme MyiOSApp archive \
    -archivePath /Users/username/Desktop/MyiOSApp.xcarchive

xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa \
    -archivePath "/Users/username/Desktop/MyiOSApp.xcarchive" \
    -exportPath "/Users/username/Desktop/MyiOSApp.ipa" \
    -exportProvisioningProfile "MyCompany Distribution Profile"
```

Comment: U can export the using the xcode directly why command line

Comment: I'm looking to automate the process using bash scripts